# HDD operations slow server down, hangs completely

Tags: linux, debian, hard-drive, io

When running a tar cvzf command or copying large folders on the production server, the CPU load goes up to 8.5 (running on 8 cores) and the whole system hangs, neither apache is responding to any calls until the operation is finished.

The server is running on Debian 6, all updates to date, and shouldn't lack any resources (8 core Intel Xeon @ 2.53 Ghz, 16 GB RAM, 4 * 500 GB HDD with 39% usage, RAID 10).

Is this type of behavior normal, or could this be a HDD fault?

There are also lots of pictures on the server (~290.000 + their thumbs) and lots of smaller zip archives (~1500), could their indexing cause this?

Comment: What RAID controller are you using?http://supportex.net/2010/11/determine-raid-controller-type-model/

Comment: Not sure, /proc/mdstat doesn't exist, lspci returns pcilib: Cannot open /proc/bus/pci, lspci: Cannot find any working access method.

Comment: CPU load of 8.5%? Or load average of 8.5? [The load average is not necessarily related to the actual system load.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_%28computing%29#Unix-style_load_calculation)

Comment: Load average. It is related to the actual load, I'm talking about the number that shows the load average for the last 1 minute, and it does go up onlyy after I run the commands, then goes straight down when they finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run this command under [nice](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nice). Before doing that you should run [vmstat](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/vmstat8.html) and [iostat](http://linux.die.net/man/1/iostat) so to get a better picture of what is going on.

If space is not an issue for you, remove the compress flag as when it comes to images,archives etc it is a waste of CPU time.